# Virtualmin Multiple PHP versions on CentOS 7

Tags: php, shell, centos7, webmin, virtualmin

I am successfully running PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.1 on my VPS CentOS7.
with this tut;
https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/multiplephp

After that I wanted to install PHP 7.2, 
I successfully installed that too with;
yum install rh-php72 rh-php72-php-mysqlnd rh-php72-php-gd

But unfortunately virtualmin do NOT see 7.2. 
Its not even listed in home dashboard "PHP Versions". 
It just shows 5.6 and 7.1.
But in the package list, I can see 7.2 is installed :/

I have another CentOS 7, and its running 3 versions perfectly.

Any idea that is causing this? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/multiplephp Did you do this bit? "Once you have completed the installation of a second PHP version on your server, you can verify that Virtualmin sees it by logging into Virtualmin, and clicking System Settings -> Re-Check Config."

Comment: yes I did that too but webmin/virtualmin still do not see the new 7.2

Comment: The following PHP versions are available : 5.6.39 (/bin/php-cgi), 7.1.8 (/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin/php-cgi), 5.6 (mod_php)